# Horizontal RecyclerView wih variable item height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal oriented RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout as its direct child. Recycler matches parent's widht, and sets its height accordingly to item's view height. The problem - Recycler can't increase or decrease its height depending on item's view height.

For example, 3 visible items on start of screen has similar 100dp height. Next, i scroll - and see 200 dp height item. It will partialy fir 100dp window and user won't see all content.

Does anyone face wiht this problem?

Comment: Did you find solution to the problem? I am in the same boat now

Comment: The problem was in COnstraintLayout. I don't know exact reasong, but i've just recreted entire layout using RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout and all work fine)

Comment: Your scenario is different then. I have no ConstraintLayout in my layout so I am sure its not related to that. My layout is made of two RecyclerView (RV) in NestedScrollView. I am not sure if that contributes to the problem but I ended up using ViewPager instead. I would come back to using RV if I get a better solution but for now, am gonna stick it ViewPager layout. Thanks for sharing your solution

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you should set measurement cache disable with your LinearLayoutManager and request layout after scrolled.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
layoutManager.setMeasurementCacheEnabled(false);

YourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
YourRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            layoutManager.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Comment: wow, this is very helpful. too old answer though. :D Thanks bro